# FormsAuthentication - User Data handling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

In the user-data portion of the FormsAuthentication ticket, i want to put in a user class instead of the comma delimited list of roles. I'll then need to read  user-data and turn it back into a usable user class. Does any one know of a tutorial/blog, which can help implement user-data portion of the authentication ticket? The user class has the following properties

- Roles : comma delimited list of roles
- TicketId: string
- Reference: string
- SubType: string
- Email: string

I think i have seen an example detailing this approach on codeproject but can't find it now.

I have already setup FormsAuthentication, having user-data portion as comma delimited list of roles. I have successfully pulled the roles from the ticket as well.

Update#1: Looks like i'll nee to serialize the class to string and then de-serialize the string to class. Kind of confuse on this step.

Comment: If you are updating an old application, then finding a solution to de-serialize is more suitable in this scenario. But if you are building a new application, why don't you try to use the new Claims Identity Model provided by Microsoft. You can add any number of claims (e.g. Email Claim, Ticket Id Claim at the time of login and retrieve them later from Identity Model.

Comment: We are using sql membership provider. I'll look into identity.